# Authentication issue with cron job on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm having trouble getting a cron job to execute a script.

`Crontab -l` contains the following:

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command

SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/user/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/rob/scripts

*/1 * * * * /bin/bash /home/rob/scripts/scan2.sh >> /home/rob/scripts/scan.log 2>&1
0 1 * * * /bin/bash /home/rob/scripts/trimdb.sh
0 1 * * * /bin/bash /home/rob/scripts/sortf.sh
```

I can see that the cron job is being executed at the correct times within `/var/log/syslog` as below without any errors:

```
May 28 21:38:01 net CRON[1899]: (rob) CMD (/bin/bash /home/rob/scripts/scan2.sh >> /home/rob/scripts/scan.log 2>&1)
May 28 21:39:01 net CRON[1915]: (rob) CMD (/bin/bash /home/rob/scripts/scan2.sh >> /home/rob/scripts/scan.log 2>&1)
May 28 21:40:01 net CRON[1931]: (rob) CMD (/bin/bash /home/rob/scripts/scan2.sh >> /home/rob/scripts/scan.log 2>&1)
May 28 21:41:01 net CRON[1947]: (rob) CMD (/bin/bash /home/rob/scripts/scan2.sh >> /home/rob/scripts/scan.log 2>&1)
```

However when I check the cron service, I can see there is a auth error:

```
May 28 21:46:01 net sudo[2146]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
May 28 21:46:01 net sudo[2146]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [rob]
May 28 21:46:01 net CRON[2134]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user rob
May 28 21:47:01 net CRON[2152]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user rob by (uid=0)
May 28 21:47:01 net CRON[2153]: (rob) CMD (/bin/bash /home/rob/scripts/scan2.sh >> /home/rob/scripts/scan.log 2>&1)
May 28 21:47:01 net sudo[2164]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
May 28 21:47:01 net sudo[2164]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [rob]
May 28 21:47:01 net CRON[2152]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user rob
```

The script runs perfectly when running it manually.

Thanks for the assistance.

Contents of scan.log:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
/home/rob/scripts/scan2.sh: line 43: grep: command not found
/home/rob/scripts/scan2.sh: line 1: date: command not found
/home/rob/scripts/scan2.sh: line 2: date: command not found
/home/rob/scripts/scan2.sh: line 3: date: command not found
/home/rob/scripts/scan2.sh: line 5: date: command not found
/home/rob/scripts/scan2.sh: line 6: date: command not found
/home/rob/scripts/scan2.sh: line 7: date: command not found
/home/rob/scripts/scan2.sh: line 41: grep: command not found
```

Comment: This is "rob" or "root" crontab?

Comment: Do you see something useful in `scan.log`?

Comment: this is rob crontab

Comment: Added the contents of scan.log to the question

Comment: It sounds like you're asking us to debug `/home/rob/scripts/scan2.sh` without showing us the code in `/home/rob/scripts/scan2.sh `.

Comment: I'm asking what `pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [rob]` means within the cron logs.

Comment: What's in `scan2.sh`?

Comment: Looks like something in `scan2.sh` is trying to run `sudo` and that `sudo` wants your password for authentication, but it can't get it because the cron job is not associated with a terminal and therefore `pam_auth` (which is the library that `sudo` uses to prompt for a password) reports a failure. You can use `sudo -A` with `$SUDO_ASKPASS` to get around this. If you do that, make certain that only your UID is able to read, write and run your password-provider program.

Comment: Thanks ottomeister, there was a sudo in the script.  Your solution worked great. Make your comment an answer and I will mark as so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something in `scan2.sh` is trying to run `sudo`, and that `sudo` wants your password for authentication.  However, `sudo` can not obtain your password because the cron job is not associated with a terminal and therefore `pam_auth` (which is the library that `sudo` uses to prompt for a password) reports a failure.

To get around this you can use `sudo -A` with a `$SUDO_ASKPASS` environment variable set to the name of a program (it can be just a shell script) that will provide your password.  If you do that, make certain that only your UID is able to read, write and run your password-provider program.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue with below steps:

Please check if password of that user should not be expried.

> chage -l scfuser

If it's expired then set with below step:

> passwd scfuser